# Searchable video library with indexed XMP Dublin Core metadata

Tags: indexing, xmp, adobe-premiere, dublin-core

my company is producing a large amount of video files which are being tagged using Adobe Premiere during the editing. The tags are stored in the Dublin Core fields of the XMP section of the metadata window (ie : keywords, title, author, etc...).

They would need to have an online library of these videos, with search capability to find the video rushes based on the set tags.

Has anyone already implemented something similar and would be willing to share experience ?

thanks a lot

Adam